# Firebase Storage: Fetch all Metadata when using listAll()

Tags: firebase-storage, metadata

Assuming there are 1000+ thumbnails stored in Firebase Storage.

Next to the paths I need the meta data, too.

Is it possible to fetch not only the list of files using `listAll()`, but also to fetch the meta data ... with just one request?

Calling `getMetaData()` for each single file is time consuming. It also adds to the number of reads, thus increasing costs?

Or, do I need to write a function scanning the files and save the info to a TXT file?
I would like to avoid that. I would also like to avoid adding a DB.

**Note**

`.listAll(fetchMetaData:true)` would be brilliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to get the metadata for a list of files. You will have to get the metadata separate for each file. If this is prohibitive, consider storing the metadata in an additional place that is more suited for such an operation - such as one of Firebase's cloud-hosted databases.